# Fasttext skipgram running slow

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

Below is my code, I am running this on python 2.7

```
model = fasttext.skipgram('train1.txt', 'model', dim = 200, minn=0,
                          maxn=0, loss='hs', lr=0.1, min_count =1,
                          epoch=1, thread =64)
```

I am running this on google cloud platform on a datalab based instance, its 64 cpu and 410GB RAM. The size of train.txt is 26GB, its taking more than 6 hours. How can I tune it?

Comment: how large is your model?

Comment: @Primusa The model.bin file is 14GB, when the code was running it used 260GB of RAM

Comment: I mean your model architecture

Comment: @Primusa How can I see model architecture? I am looking for the command but not able to figure it out.

Comment: oh I thought it was a neural network